# What is the underlying container in a Java String?

Tags: java, string

Is it just a char array?

Comment: +1 for your curiosity... check: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html

Comment: @irreputable ... but it isn't.

Comment: good question (+1) but even better would be to have a look yourself. Eclipse and probably any other major IDE attach the JDK sources automatically, so you can just check to see what's there. And if you want to see more than the contents of rt.jar, get the complete sources from the OpenJDK project: http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/

Comment: Generally, encapsulation should make this an implementation detail. Only the public methods and the serialized form should be expected by consumers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, plus some meta-data, like a start and end index (because that char array can be shared across strings, for example, when you create substrings).

Looking at the source for `java.lang.String`, you see the following instance fields:

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];

/** The offset is the first index of the storage that is used. */
private final int offset;

/** The count is the number of characters in the String. */
private final int count;

/** Cache the hash code for the string */
private int hash; // Default to 0
```

Comment: And some methods and algorithms... as `String` is an object and not a primitive `datatype`

Comment: @Garis yes, but that's not the container, that's the sugar on top